# When $|z_1+\ldots + z_n| = |z_1| + \ldots + |z_n|$.

Tags: complex-analysis

**Problem:** Prove that the equality $|z_1+\ldots + z_n| = |z_1| + \ldots + |z_n|$ holds if and only if $z_k/z_l \ge 0$ for any integer $k$ and $l$, $1 \le k, l \le n$, for which $z_l\ne0$.

**My attempt:** First, when we think geometrically the statement above makes sense because $z_k/z_l \ge 0$ means that all the numbers are on a line. Therefore, the equality holds. However, I am trying to prove this analytically, what I've done is below:

> Assume $z_k/z_l \ge 0$ for any integer $k$ and $l$, $1 \le k, l \le
> > n$, for which $z_l\ne0$.Then, for particular $k$ and $l$ there is a
>   positive real number $m$ such that $z_k=mz_l$. Thus, $z_k+z_l=(m+1)z_l
> > \Rightarrow |z_k+z_l|=(m+1)|z_l|=|z_k|+|z_l|$.

However, the result I reached above is only for 2 complex numbers, and I cannot proceed to show that it holds for $n$ complex numbers. Could you give a hint about the solution?

Comment: Induction. You have $\lvert z_1 + \dotsc + z_n\rvert \leqslant \lvert z_1 + \dotsc + z_{n-1}\rvert + \lvert z_n\rvert \leqslant \lvert z_1\rvert + \dotsc + \lvert z_n\rvert$, and since the outer two are equal you also have $\lvert z_1 + \dotsc + z_{n-1}\rvert = \lvert z_1\rvert + \dotsc + \lvert z_{n-1}\rvert$.

Comment: Indeed the case $n=2$ suffices and then, even the elementary approach using real and imaginary parts works. To be solved is $$(x+u)^2+(y+v)^2=x^2+y^2+u^2+v^2+2\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\sqrt{u^2+v^2}$$ that is, $$xu+yv=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\sqrt{u^2+v^2}$$ Squaring again yields the necessary condition $$2xyuv=y^2u^2+x^2v^2$$ that is, $$(xv-yu)^2=0$$ thus $$x+iy=c\,(u+iv)$$ for some real $c$ and it remains to prove that $c\geqslant0$ using the signs before the second squaring, qed.

Comment: You should declare what set these $z_i$ belong to somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

This is a hint as you asked (the full proof is in Ahlfor's Complex Analysis).

Suppose equality holds for any $n\ge 2$. Then we must have $|z_1+z_2|=|z_1|+|z_2|$ by cancelling terms. Now by the already established result we have $z_1/z_2\ge 0$ (assuming $z_2\ne 0$). But the numberings of $z_i$ are arbitrary and so the ratio of any two non zero terms is positive.

For the converse use the fact that $|1+\frac{z_2}{z_1}+\cdots+\frac{z_n}{z_1}|=1+\frac{z_2}{z_1}+\cdots+\frac{z_n}{z_1}$ and write $|z_1+\cdots+z_n|$ as $|z_1|(1+\frac{z_2}{z_1}+\cdots+\frac{z_n}{z_1})$ (assuming $z_1\ne 0$).

Comment: You cannot deduce, for example, $|z_2 + z_3| = |z_2| + |z_3|$. There may be something wrong in your 2nd paragraph.

Comment: Does $|z_1+\ldots + z_n| = |z_1| + \ldots + |z_n|$ imply $|z_2 + z_3| = |z_2| + |z_3|$?

Comment: Indeed. Note that in this case $|z_1|+\cdots+|z_n|=|z_1+\cdots+z_n|$ is at most $|z_1|+|z_2+z_3|+\cdots+|z_n|$ which is at most $|z_1|+\cdots+|z_n|$. So we must have $|z_1|+|z_2+z_3|+\cdots+|z_n|=|z_1|+\cdots+|z_n|$. Hence $|z_2+z_3|=|z_2|+|z_3|$.

Answer (score 0):

The comment about induction by Daniel Fischer looks fine. For a direct proof:

Find $\ell$ so that $z_\ell =|z_\ell| e^{i\theta} \neq 0$. Then (show and) use the inequality:
  $$ {\rm Re} \left( e^{-i \theta} (z_1 + \cdots + z_n ) \right) \leq \sum_k |z_k| $$
and study the case when there is equality. Alternative: Look at equality in:

$$ \left| \sum_k z_k \right|^2 = \sum_{k,\ell} z_k \bar{z}_\ell \leq \sum_{k,\ell} |z_k|\; |z_\ell| = \left( \sum_k |z_k|\right)^2 $$